# what is the value of an ignored parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, parameters, typeof

I was wondering what is the value of an ignored parameter in JS. Lets say that a function takes 2 values as parameters and we only provide one on the call. What is the value of the other one? I thought it would be undefined but the following piece of code only displays "1".

```
var test = function(par1, par2){
    document.write(par1.toString());
    document.write(par2.toString());
    if(typeof par2 === "undefined"){
        document.write('undefined');
    }
};

test(1);
```

the following code would work:

```
var test = function(par1, par2){
    document.write(par1.toString());
    document.write(par2);
    if(par2 === undefined){
        document.write('undefined');
    }
};

test(1);
```

Comment: it is `undefined` - your code is throwing because `toString` on `undefined` fails.

Comment: just realised that I was using toString() for the undefined param. When removed it writes "undefined" why is my if statement not working though?

Comment: because it throws an error! check out your browser's console or put it in a `try..catch` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When parameter is not supplied, its value is `undefined`. Note that variable itself is available (after all, its name is already supplied to a function via arguments list, and it's the name that counts in JavaScript), so there's no need to check it via `typeof var === 'undefined'` to avoid those pesky ReferenceErrors.

`undefined` is a special value in JavaScript. While you cannot call any method on it (fails with `undefined is not an object` Error), you still can use it in expressions and function calls. In this particular case `document.write` will implicitly convert this value to String before displaying it; the result will be a *String* - `'undefined'`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jy4ys68k/).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var test = function(par1, par2){
    if(par2 === undefined){
        document.write('undefined');
    }
};

test(1);
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jjeq58ad/)**

You can also check, if your attributes are set. Example:

```
var test = function(par1, par2){
    if(par1 === undefined){
        document.write('par1 is undefined');
    }else{
        document.write('par1 is set');
    }
    if(par2 === undefined){
        document.write('par2 is undefined');
    }else{
        document.write('par2 is set');
    }
};

test(1);
```

And output will be:

```
par1 is set
par2 is undefined
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jjeq58ad/1/)**

Hope it'll help :)